# Equivalent of ASSOC and FTYPE in Linux?

Tags: linux, shell, command-line, file-association

Is there an equivalent of ASSOC and FTYPE in Linux?

On Windows I am able to define a file type with ftype. As an example:

```
assoc .pl=PerlScript
ftype PerlScript=perl.exe %1 %*
```

When this is done, I can double click on the file and it will run with the specified program.

In Linux (I'm on Ubuntu 12.04 using KDE desktop) I'm having trouble opening Python GUI scripts by double clicking them, seemingly because of an association problem at the GUI level but not at the terminal (it runs correctly if I run it from the terminal, but not if I double-click it in which case nothing apparently happens).

Comment: related to the title: [`xdg-mime`](https://portland.freedesktop.org/doc/xdg-mime.html) (it may be overridden by DE). Possibly related to the body of the question: [How do I run executable scripts in Nautilus?](http://askubuntu.com/q/286621/3712)

Answer (score 1):

Files have to made made executable on linux:

```
$ chmod ugo+x my_file.py
```

http://ss64.com/bash/chmod.html

Comment: The file is executable. The shebang seems to be respected when I execute from the terminal. When I double-click it is not.

Comment: From the command line I can run it either with `python script.py` or `./script.py`. Either way works. I do notice that when run the first way, the python specified overrides the shebang. Having said that, the focus of my question is about how to get the correct behavior from the GUI when double-clicking or right-clicking the the file icon and going to "python," not the command line. I tried to use System Settings > File Associations and for x-python I entered the command "/usr/bin/python2 %f" but this doesn't cause it to use /usr/bin/python2 when I right-click and go to python.  Thanks.